# AttributeError: 'TestCaseFunction' object has no attribute 'wasSuccessful' (UnitTest to Pytest)

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, python-unittest

I am converting my unittest test cases to `pytest`.
While running my py file, the script does its function fine (device reboot) but my test script shows the following failure:

```
================================================================================================ FAILURES =================================================================================================
_________________________________________________________________________________________ TestReboot.test_reboot __________________________________________________________________________________________
../../custom_xmlrunner/custom_unittest_runner.py:245: in run
    self.write_result(result)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <device_reboot.TestReboot testMethod=test_reboot>, result = <TestCaseFunction test_reboot>

    def write_result(self, result):
        """
        Write the result of the test-case, like:

            -----------------------
            TESTCASE: my_test_case
            RESULT: PASS
            -----------------------

        This too is implicitly called at the end of the test-case.
        """
        self.write_log('-' * 60)
        self.write_log('TESTCASE: {0}'.format(self._testMethodName))

>       if result.wasSuccessful():
E       AttributeError: 'TestCaseFunction' object has no attribute 'wasSuccessful'

../../custom_xmlrunner/custom_unittest_runner.py:292: AttributeError
```

Comment: So, can you show your test code, and what you changed for pytest?

Comment: Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)